# Get access tokens of groupon

Tags: python, selenium, beautifulsoup, xmlhttprequest

I would like to retrieve the source code of a web page but I have a message that says "access denied". I tried to use the users agent to fix this problem it worked for a few but after the same error came back. I saw that one of the solutions was to recover the tokens of the page from where my question. How to recover tokens from a page or a website.

url of the website : https://www.groupon.com/browse/boston?category=food-and-drink

```
#import needed object
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from fake_useragent import UserAgent

#put the url of the groupon page in the object url
url = "https://www.groupon.com/browse/boston?category=food-and-drink"
#print the url on the screen, return an object of type NoneType
print(url)

#create a UserAgent object
ua = UserAgent()
#put a random UserAgent in the object userAgent
userAgent = ua.random
#print the userAgent on the screen, return an object of type NoneType
print(userAgent)
#initialise the object options with the options of chrome webdriver 
selenium.webdriver.chrome.options.Options
options = Options()
#add a argument in the object option, return an object of type NoneType
options.add_argument(f'user-agent={userAgent}')
#define the option of chrome webdriver
 options.headless = True
#create a webdriver object, return the object driver of type 
selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver.WebDriver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options, executable_path=r'C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\Scripts\chromedriver.exe')
#get the url, return an object of type NoneType
driver.get(url)
#create a beautifulsoup object, return an object of type bs4.BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,features="html.parser")

#select body, return the object codeSource of type list
codeSource = soup.select('body')
#print codeSource on the screen, return an object of type NoneType 
print(codeSource)
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fNSw.png)

Comment: Welcome to SO, add your code and result to question in order to community members can reproduce your problem, nobody will type your code from image to solve your problem, adding image of code is bad practice, read MCVE before asking question

Comment: Read [Terms Of Service](https://www.groupon.com/legal/termsofservice#use-of-the-site),  4th point , seems like your IP blocked because hitting bulk of request on their server !!!

Comment: how can I fix that? Is there a way to use this website without sending a request to their server?

Comment: Is that you want to do this necessarily in the headless mode? Coz in the normal mode I could get the page source without any issues

Comment: Okay. Thanks  @SnR it works now perfectly

Comment: @BenyDZIENGUE cool as this works for you I have posted this as the answer, kindly mark it as the accepted one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting this issue in the headless mode, in the normal mode it would work fine. So you can remove option.headless = true & you will get the page source without any issues